# Find integral $ \int \frac{dx}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2} $ $(a\neq b)$ with partial fractions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find integral $ \int \frac{dx}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2} $  $(a\neq b)$.

I am trying to use "Method of Partial Fractions" and here is my work.

$\frac{1}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}=\frac{A}{x+a}+\frac{B}{(x+a)^2}+\frac{C}{x+b}+\frac{D}{(x+b)^2}$

equating $x$ to $a$ and $b$ I found $B$ and $D$ equal $\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}$

But how do I find $C$ and $A$?

Comment: Try to simplify the right side then compare the coefficient of power of $x$ on both sides.

Comment: Why you posted new question , you may edit your previous one

Comment: You find $C$ and $A$ by the method used in the examples in the book! What's the problem with that???